# Problems when using EntityFilteringFeature and SelectableEntityFilteringFeature with Jersey 2

Tags: rest, jax-rs, servlet-filters, jersey-2.0

I'm new to Jersey 2 and JAX-RS, so probably I'm missing something.
What I'm trying to do is a test program to define a coding style in rest services developing.
The test was written in JAVA and uses JERSEY 2.22.2, JDK 1.8.31, MOXY AS JSON Provider.

I defined a Resource with GET methods to support LIST/DETAIL. Due to the size of my POJO, I used some filters and everything was fine.

```
// 1) First of all I defined the annotation.


@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@EntityFiltering 
public @interface MyDetailView {

public static class Factory extends AnnotationLiteral<MyDetailView>
    implements MyDetailView {

    private Factory() {
    }

    public static MyDetailView get() {
        return new Factory();
    }
}


// 2) Once defined the annotation, I used to 
// programmaticaly exclude the list of subItems in the response...


@XmlRootElement
public class MyPojo {

...     


    //*** THIS SHOULD BE FILTERED IF THE ANNOTATION IS NOT SPECIFIED IN THE RESPONSE ***
    @MyDetailView
    private List<SubItem> subItems = new ArrayList<SubItem>();

    public List<SubItem> getSubItems() {
        return subItems;
    }

    public void setSubItems(List<SubItem> subItems) {
        this.subItems = subItems;
    }

}


// 3) I registered the EntityFilteringFeature

    public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig { 

    public ApplicationConfig() {

        ....
        register(EntityFilteringFeature.class);

    }


// 4) Finally, I wrote the code to include/exclude the subItems


/* 
The Resource class has getCollection() and getItem() methods... 

getCollection() adds the annotation only if filterStyle="detail"
getItem() always add the annotation 

*/

@Path(....)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class MyResource extends SecuredResource {

    //filterStyle -> "detail" means MyDetailAnnotation
    @GET
    public Response getCollection(
       @QueryParam("filterStyle") String filterStyle,
       @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {


        //THIS CODE AFFECTS THE RESPONSE 
        boolean detailedResponse = "detail".equals(filterStyle);      
        Annotation[] responseAnnotations = detailedResponse 
            ? new Annotation[0]
            : new Annotation[]{MyDetailView.Factory.get()}; 

        //pojo collection...        
        MyPagedCollection myCollection = new MyPagedCollection();

        //.....

        ResponseBuilder builder = Response.ok();

        return builder.entity(myCollection, responseAnnotations).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    public Response getItem(@PathParam("{id}") String idS, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
        MyPOJO pojo = ... 

        Annotation[] responseAnnotations = new Annotation[]{MyDetailView.Factory.get()};

        return Response.ok().entity(pojo, responseAnnotations).build();
    }
}
```

After the first test, I tried to use the SelectableEntityFilteringFeature to allow the client to ask for specific fields in the detail, so I changed the ApplicationConfig

```
    public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig { 

    public ApplicationConfig() {

        ....
        register(EntityFilteringFeature.class);

        register(SelectableEntityFilteringFeature.class);   
        property(SelectableEntityFilteringFeature.QUERY_PARAM_NAME, "fields");          
    }
```

and I've add the "fields" QueryParam to the Resource getItem() method...

```
@GET
@Path("/{id}")
public Response getDetail(@PathParam({id}) String id, 
        @QueryParam("fields") String fields,
        @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {

        ....
```

But as long as I registered the SelectableEntityFilteringFeature class, the EntityFilteringFeature class stopped working. I tried to add "fields" parameter to one of the Resource methods, it worked perfectly. But the MyDetailAnnotation was completely useless.

I tried to register it using a DynamicFeature

```
public class MyDynamicFeature implements DynamicFeature { 

@Override
public void configure(ResourceInfo resourceInfo, FeatureContext context) {
    if ("MyResource".equals(resourceInfo.getResourceClass().getSimpleName())
                && "getItem".equals(resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().getName())) {

            //*** IS THE CORRECT WAY TO BIND A FEATURE TO A METHOD? ***
            //
            context.register(SelectableEntityFilteringFeature.class);
            context.property(SelectableEntityFilteringFeature.QUERY_PARAM_NAME, "fields");

    }       
}
```

Now the questions:

1) Why registering both the SelectableEntityFilteringFeature feature breaks the EntityFilteringFeature?

2) What is the correct way to bind a feature to a method with the DynamicFeature interface?

Thanks in advance.
This is my first post to Stack Overflow, I hope it was written complaining the rules.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you can't. It appears to be a bug as of 2.25.1 and up to 2.26(that I tested with). https://github.com/jersey/jersey/issues/3523

Answer (score 0):

`SelectableEntityFilteringFeature` implictily registers `EntityFilteringFeature` (As mentioned [here](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.9/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/message/filtering/SelectableEntityFilteringFeature.html)). So I don't see a need to add this.

Since you need Annotation based filtering, you can **exclude** registering `SelectableEntityFilteringFeature`.

You can just do,

```
// Set entity-filtering scope via configuration.
.property(EntityFilteringFeature.ENTITY_FILTERING_SCOPE, new Annotation[] {MyDetailView.Factory.get()})
// Register the EntityFilteringFeature.
.register(EntityFilteringFeature.class)
// Further configuration of ResourceConfig.
```

You can refer to [this](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/entity-filtering.html#ef.annotations) example for usage and [this](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/entity-filtering.html#ef.example.server.registration) example for registering the filter.

So  you can remove `SelectableEntityFilteringFeature` and try just the above mentioned way to register it.

Comment: Thanks. But this is what I did and it worked (the only difference was that I didn't specify the property in the ResourceConifg subclass, I've added the annotation in the Resource method. My goal now is to use the SelectableEntityFilteringFeature in the detail method (using the QueryParam "fields", for clarity I've added the different method signature to the code). In the mean time I want to leave the getCollection() as it is (it filters the response via MyDetailView annotation exactly as explained in the links you posted). The problem is that the unchanged getCollection() stopped filtering.

Comment: The poster wants to use both EntityFilteringFeature and SelectableEntityFilteringFeature, so this is not really an answer. It just describes how to use only annotation based EntityFilteringFeature